# html css javascript i need my navigation window to close as soon as user clicks on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a label tag that acts like a navigation the label ul li are embedded in a div that acts like a navigation.

when the user clicks on the hamburger button a background color covers the whole page covering everything and it stays like this until the user clicks the x to close it.. well its cumbersome and not user friendly
i need a js or jquery call to immediately close the exploded div (navigation) as soon as the user clicks on a href or button

i don't have a problem with some of the links but when a link points to an id like this

current auctions then things get sticky especially if the user clicks on current auctions twice it just stays there staring at me

here is the code and some pictures of what it looks like

```
<style>

.navigation-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.navigation-button {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7.5rem;
    right: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2000;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(#000, .1);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation-background {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 8rem;
    right: 2rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 114, 121, 1) 35%,
    rgba(0, 212, 255, 0.5709286277602523) 100%);
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: transform .8s cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
}

.navigation-nav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1500;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.navigation-list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}



.navigation-item {
    margin: 1rem;
}

.navigation-item {
    word-spacing: 1rem;
}

.navigation-link:link,
.navigation-link:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #fff 50%);
    background-size: 270%;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.navigation-link:link > span,
.navigation-link:visited > span {
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation-link:hover,
.navigation-link:active {
    background-position: 100%;
    color: #8794FA;
    transform: translateX(1rem);
}

.navigation-checkbox:checked ~ .navigation-background {
    transform: scale(80);
}

.navigation-checkbox:checked ~ .navigation-nav {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

/*-------------------icon --------------------*/

.navigation-icon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
}

.navigation-icon::before,
.navigation-icon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.navigation-icon::before {
    top: -.8rem;
}

.navigation-icon::after {
    top: .8rem;
}

.navigation-icon,
.navigation-icon::before,
.navigation-icon::after {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline-block
}

.navigation-button:hover > .navigation-icon::before {
    top: -1rem;
}

.navigation-button:hover > .navigation-icon::after {
    top: 1rem;
}

/*------------------ icon appear and disappear -------*/

.navigation-checkbox:checked + .navigation-button > .navigation-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation-checkbox:checked + .navigation-button > .navigation-icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.navigation-checkbox:checked + .navigation-button > .navigation-icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]

</style>
```

```
<body>
<nav th:fragment="nav.html">
    <!--   NAVIGATION-->
    <div class="navigation">
        <input type="checkbox" class="navigation-checkbox" id="navi-toggle">
        <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation-button">
            <span class="navigation-icon">&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <div class="navigation-background">&nbsp;</div>
        <nav class="navigation-nav">
            <ul class="navigation-list">
                <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="/#first-auction">current auctions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">past auctions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a href="https://server22.maxanet.com/cgi-bin/mnregister.cgi?restaubid"
                                               class="navigation-link">login</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a href="https://server22.maxanet.com/cgi-bin/mnregister.cgi?restaubid"
                                               class="navigation-link">register</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a href="https://server22.maxanet.com/cgi-bin/mnregister.cgi?restaubid"
                                               class="navigation-link">update bidder's info</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a th:href="@{/about}" class="navigation-link">about</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a th:href="@{/contact}" class="navigation-link">contact</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a th:href="@{/locations}" class="navigation-link">location</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a th:href="@{/referrals}" class="navigation-link">referrals</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-item"><a th:href="@{/services}" class="navigation-link">buy new at near auction prices</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mOfo.gif)

enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy solution would be to add an **`eventListener`** to your **`nav`**. You can also attach it to the **`document`** itself and use **`Event Delegation`** approach. I added **`navigationItems`** id to your **`nav`** to get the element easier and then attach an event listener on that element. When you click an **`<a>`** tag set your **`checkbox.checked`** value to false and the menu should close.

```js
document.getElementById('navigationItems').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === 'A') { // Check if <a> tag is clicked
    document.getElementById('navi-toggle').checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <input type="checkbox" class="navigation-checkbox" id="navi-toggle">
  <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation-button">
    <span class="navigation-icon">&nbsp;</span>
  </label>
  <div class="navigation-background">&nbsp;</div>

  <nav class="navigation-nav" id="navigationItems">
    <ul class="navigation-list">
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="/#first-auction">current auctions</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">past auctions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```